# JDBC connection to AS400 creates Nullpointer

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I am working on an java application running on an AS400 server.

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
        String doTrace = AppProp.getInstance().getProperty("trace.enabled");
        if("true".equals(doTrace)){
            Trace.setTraceAllOn(true);
            String tracefile = AppProp.getInstance().getProperty("trace.file");
            new File(tracefile).createNewFile();
            Trace.setFileName(tracefile);
            Trace.setTraceOn(true);
            log.warn("Trace Enabled");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);

    }
```

and this

```
    try {

        if ("true".equals(local)) {
            user = "*CURRENT";
            password = "*CURRENT";
        }
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    } finally{
        //do something here...
    }
```

With the url beeing jdbc:as400://10.65.1.31/QSYS.LIB

When running on a windows server connecting to the AS400 i works fine, but when running locally on the AS400 i get the exception:

```
at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400SQLConnection.getConnection(AS400SQLConnection.java:66)
    at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400FileAccess.initConnection(AS400FileAccess.java:62)
    at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400FileAccess.<init>(AS400FileAccess.java:50)
    at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400FileIterator.<init>(AS400FileIterator.java:23)
    at com.df.info2000.wscom.WSCOMTransferFileThradsafe.connectAS400Iterator(WSCOMTransferFileThradsafe.java:674)
    at com.df.info2000.wscom.WSCOMTransferFileThradsafe.initialize(WSCOMTransferFileThradsafe.java:132)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:181)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:29)
    at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:32)
    at java.lang.NullPointerException.<init>(NullPointerException.java:36)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.SocketContainerUnix.getInputStream(SocketContainerUnix.java:65)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.signonConnect(AS400ImplRemote.java:1834)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.getConnection(AS400ImplRemote.java:957)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.connect(AS400ImplRemote.java:392)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService(AS400.java:822)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:2764)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.prepareConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1040)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.initializeConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:931)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.connect(AS400JDBCDriver.java:355)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
    at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400SQLConnection.getConnection(AS400SQLConnection.java:51)
    ... 6 more
```

From the trace log i have now found this:

```
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Error retrieving GSSToken:
org.ietf.jgss.GSSException, major code: 11, minor code: 0
major string: General failure, unspecified at GSSAPI level
minor string: Error: com.ibm.security.krb5.KrbException, status code: 0
message: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such path or directory. /etc/krb5/krb5.conf
at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:181)
at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:29)
at org.ietf.jgss.GSSException.<init>(GSSException.java:181)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.i18n.I18NException.throwGSSException(I18NException.java:5)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.krb5.bb.b(bb.java:32)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.krb5.bb.a(bb.java:154)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.krb5.bb.<init>(bb.java:36)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getNameElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:44)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.a(GSSManagerImpl.java:19)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.a(GSSNameImpl.java:17)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.canonicalize(GSSNameImpl.java:0)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:173)
at com.ibm.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:14)
at com.ibm.as400.access.TokenManager.getGSSToken(TokenManager.java:35)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.signon(AS400.java:3359)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService(AS400.java:821)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:2764)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.prepareConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1040)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.initializeConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:931)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.connect(AS400JDBCDriver.java:355)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400SQLConnection.getConnection(AS400SQLConnection.java:67)
at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400FileAccess.initConnection(AS400FileAccess.java:62)
at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400FileAccess.<init>(AS400FileAccess.java:50)
at com.df.info2000.as400Worker.AS400FileIterator.<init>(AS400FileIterator.java:23)
at com.df.info2000.wscom.WSCOMTransferFileThradsafe.connectAS400Iterator(WSCOMTransferFileThradsafe.java:674)
at com.df.info2000.wscom.WSCOMTransferFileThradsafe.initialize(WSCOMTransferFileThradsafe.java:132)
at com.df.info2000.wscom.MainExtract.main(MainExtract.java:62)
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Signing-on without prompting...
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Current userID in EBCDIC: 
D3 C5 C3 D4 D6 C8 40 40 40 40 
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Current userID: 'LECMOH'
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Current userID in EBCDIC: 
D3 C5 C3 D4 D6 C8 40 40 40 40 
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Current userID: 'LECMOH'
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Sign-on completed.
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Service disconnected implementation: as-signon
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Establishing connection to server: as-database
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Starting a local socket to as-signon
```

Can you see what may be the problem ?

We are running on an AS400 version  R610

For some reason the program is trying to authenticate the user with Kerberos - even if i provide the parameter AuthenticationMethod=client

Now i am trying to get some remote debugging up and running so we are modifying our CL command to this:

```
 RUNJVA     CLASS('com.df.info2000.wscom.MainExtract')    
                    CLASSPATH('/DFWSCOM/config/')               
                    OPTIMIZE(*JIT) INTERPRET(*JIT)              
                    PROP(                                       
    (os400.xrun.option 'jdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,  
    server=y,suspend=y')                                        
                     (java.security.krb5.conf                   
      '/QIBM/ProdData/OS400/NetworkAuthentication/krb5.conf')   
                                           (java.ext.dirs    
                    '/DFWSCOM/lib/')) GCHINL(240000000)         
                    GCHMAX(*NOMAX) JOB(WSCOVFC) OUTPUT(*NONE)
```

But it ends with this message:
Message . . . . :   An error occurred during JVM_OnLoad processing of *SRVPGM 
  JDWP15. The error code is 3.
Årsag . . . . . :   The JVM_OnLoad function did not complete for *SRVPGM
  JDWP15 because of error code 3. The error codes are defined as follows: 1 - 
  The JVM was unable to locate the service program. 2 - The JVM was unable to 
  activate the service program. 3 - The JVM was unable to locate the
  JVM_OnLoad function. 4 - Error code 0 was returned from the JVM_OnLoad

My AS400 guy says it doesn't understand the os400.xrun.option - can anyone see what we are doing wrong ?

Well - now we have moved the program to the prod environment to see if it would run there - and magically it would, so there is something wrong with our test AS400. So for now it works in prod, and we live with the problem on the test server...

Comment: what db2 driver are you using?

Comment: Are you actually using `QSYS.LIB` as the database name? Or is that only a 'sanitized' example?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know what have you tried so far but Just Follow this code and verify yourself and get solved...!!!

```
 Connection con = null;  

    try {  
          Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver);  
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {  
          System.out.println(e);  
          System.exit(0);  
    }  


    try {  
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://yourserver", "yourUserId", "yourPassword");  

          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  

          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM YOURLIB.YOUR_PF_FILE");  

          while (rs.next()) {  

                  String field1 = rs.getString(1);  
                  String field2 = rs.getString("fieldname");  

                  .....  
          }  catch(Exception e) {  

              .....  

          }
```

I Hope this will help you

Comment: Okay i can see my question is not very specific:
I have this code:

Comment: I get the exception at the DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass).

Comment: what exception you are getting actually? actually u need to give your db related credentials as parameters

Comment: A nullpointer exception - when running remote i give user and pass, when running locally it should be okay with *CURRENT as user and password. We have tried various combinations - but we can't get the connection

Comment: are u getting the connection object atleast just try to print it and later show the stacktrace of error

Comment: I get the exception when i try getting the connection object

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException.(NullPointerException.java:36) at com.ibm.as400.access.SocketContainerUnix.getInputStream(SocketContainerUnix.java:65) at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.signonConnect(AS400ImplRemote.java:1834) at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.getConnection(AS400ImplRemote.java:957) at

Comment: I think my problem must start at the stacktrace i found in the trace maybe ?

Comment: are u sure that everything is properly configured for as400 to use it

Comment: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]  Wed Oct 01 09:17:51 CEST 2014  Error retrieving GSSToken:
org.ietf.jgss.GSSException, major code: 11, minor code: 0
 major string: General failure, unspecified at GSSAPI level
 minor string: Error: com.ibm.security.krb5.KrbException, status code: 0
 message: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such path or directory. /etc/krb5/krb5.conf

Comment: that indicates the configuration is not done Properly

Comment: I guess my problem is i don't have much AS400 knowledge - we have found that the file is somewhere else, so maybe we can somehow tell the application where to look for it ?

Comment: We have it here - /QIBM/UserData/OS400/NetworkAuthentication/krb5.conf
Which is the default location on iSeries, so why does it look for it at /etc/krb5/krb5.conf

Comment: I have now added
  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/QIBM/UserData/OS400/NetworkAuthentication/krb5.conf");
and it finds the file - but not the credential...- but we are getting closer

Comment: find the username and password for that DSN you will get solved

Comment: I think i should try to switch the AuthenticationMetod from Kerberos to something else - do you know how ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple problems.

1. You need to upgrade your jt400.jar file, as the tracepoints don't seem to match the latest jt400.jar tracepoints.  The latest PTFs for V6R1 are SI53962 and SI53963.
2. You should be using null pointers instead of *CURRENT.  Allowing the use of *CURRENT is a security exposure for older versions of JTOpen and has been disallowed.  Consequently, your code should look like the following.

   ```
   if ("true".equals(local)) {
       user = null;
       password = null;
   }
   ```